# Connect external language server to VSCode extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, language-server-protocol

I want to implement a VSCode extension that uses the [Language Server Protocol](https://microsoft.github.io/language-server-protocol/), but I want the server component to be on an actual server (in the cloud), and not a part of the VSCode extension.

Can I set the client extension to connect to a server via websockets or HTTP?

Answer (score 4):

Multiple ServerOptions are supported when you initialize a `LanguageClient` according to the signature of `ServerOptions`.
[image]

you can use the `StreamInfo` if you want to use a real remove server as your language server. Here is a sample code to connect to your server via `WebSocket` and initialize a `LanguageClient`.

```js
const connection = connectToServer(hostname, path);
const client = new LanguageClient(
    "docfxLanguageServer",
    "Docfx Language Server",
    () => Promise.resolve<StreamInfo>({
        reader: connection,
        writer: connection,
    }),
    {});

private connectToServer(hostname: string, path: string): Duplex {
    const ws = new WebSocket(`ws://${hostname}/${path}`);
    return WebSocket.createWebSocketStream(ws);
}
```

Comment: Can't edit but `remove` -> `remote`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you can control the location of the language server, but there is another option. You do not need to implement the Language Server Protocol to, for example, provide parsing help. In that case you can implement your own convenient parsing service API (tailored to the nature of the language you want to support).

1. Within your extension you subscribe to workspace edit events using `workspace.onDidChangeTextDocument`
2. Re-start a 1sec timeout every time the file on-change event is raised
3. When the timeout expires without any further file modification, gather all relevant files and send them to your parsing server
4. In your extension, create a `DiagnosticCollection` using https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#languages.createDiagnosticCollection and replace populate it with the warnings/errors/hints resulting from the parsing server in the cloud.
5. Subscribe to other `workspace` events, e.g. `workspace.onDidOpenTextDocument` or `workspace.onDidCloseTextDocument` in order to keep the `DiagnosticCollection` content relevant