# What ServerOptions should I choose to create an instance of LanguageClient?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, language-server-protocol

I want to create a new language server extension. I use the following guide: https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/language-server-extension-guide

- For a client's side I use https://www.npmjs.com/package/vscode-languageclient
- For a server's side I'll use Java (based on https://github.com/eclipse-lsp4j/lsp4j).

I have to provide an instance of `ServerOptions` to create an instance of `LanguageClient`. But I don't know what kind of `ServerOptions` I should choose.

There are few options:

1. `Executable`
2. `NodeModule`
3. `(() => Promise<ChildProcess | StreamInfo | MessageTransports | ChildProcessInfo>)`

I guess I shouldn't use `NodeModule` because I'm going to use Java. But I don't know how to decide which other option I should choose.

What's the difference between the remaining options? What details do I need to pay attention to in order to make the right choice?

Comment: a short example for `StreamInfo`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66111960/19171308